# my code is alright still I am getting this error "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression"

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

```js
function cartReducer(state={cartitems:[]},action){
    switch(action.type)
    
    {
        case CART_ADD_ITEM:
            const item= action.payload;
            const product=state.cartitems.find(x=>x.product===item.product);
            if(product)
            {
              return{
                cartitems:state.cartitems.map(x=>x.product===product.product? item:x)
              };
            }
            return {
              cartitems:[...state.cartitems,item]
            };
    default:state;
    }


}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I am getting an error "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression" please help.

Comment: Your code is not "alright" otherwise you wouldn't be getting that error. And we need to know what line is throwing that error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something with this line, return some value or assign a value

```
default:state;
```

for example:

```
default:return {...state};
```